# Small WiFi webcam for quasi-outdoor use

Tags: wireless-networking, webcam, rugged

I’d like to have a webcam pointed toward my house, so that I can check (via Safari on iPhone) if I left the garage door open, if there’s a package on my doorstep when I’m off on a business trip, etc.

My idea is to place a small webcam inside the electric gaslight in front of my house.

[image]

General requirements:

- **WiFi**: There’s already electricity at the light post, on a separate circuit from the bulb’s switch no less.  While I love PoE, it’s just not worth the hassle of digging.
- **Small**: It should fit in the glass enclosure without having to remove the CFL bulb inside.  Or perhaps discreetly on the pole itself (see "Single piece enclosure" below).
- **Rugged**: Should be able to survive the summer (and the modest heat of a CFL or LED bulb) and winter in terms of temperature, and is sealed (or can be enclosed) to protect against moisture.
- **Still image**: Video is awesome and everything, but Mobile Safari has neither Java nor Flash.  Video can be an option, but still images are absolutely critical.

Nice-to-have:

- **Secure login**: Eh…it’s the *outside* of my house.  I’m not critically worried about security, but a password barrier to view could be a bonus.  I guess.
- **Single piece enclosure**: There’s an outlet on the light post that points right back at my house, so something that looked like a ruggedized [AirPort Express](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB321LL/A/AirPort-Express-AirTunes) with a camera pointing straight back would be absolutely *perfect*.

---

**Edit:**

- **Price**: (thanks hyperslug!) I think that $200 is a reasonable upper-bound.
- **Maybe just WiFi *but not necessarily rugged***: Upon further consideration of the problem, I realize that I already have a tough, cheap, and crystal clear [watertight box](http://outdoorproducts.com/proddetail.aspx?sku=172OP) that was purchased from a big-box [store](http://www.walmart.com/) for less than $9, IIRC.  An "[in-use](http://www.aplussupply.com/intermatic/in-use.htm)" outlet cover is also an option, and as an added bonus would blend in a bit more nicely.  If someone can recommend a regular (non-ruggedized) webcam that meets at least some of the above qualifications and happens to be smaller than "7.7in W x 3.5in H x 7.4in" in size (smaller for the "in-use" cover), I'm confident that a much cheaper DIY solution is possible.

Comment: +10 if I could... there's been some security problems in a forest I monitor + i've always wondered if there's something like this out there. good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used these but they were recommended on alt.comp.periphs.webcam via  Toms Hardware

[Panasonic BB-HCM371A](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0009PD0ZI)

Has good but not great image quality, fast frame rate and built in microphone.

[Toshiba IK-WB11A](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00017X2VQ)
Great image quality but a slow frame rate (looks stop motion-ish), no built in mic.

Comment: Those are certainly candidates, but man are they pricey.

Comment: Yep ... you might be better off with a long USB cable and spending $50 bucks on a regular webcam.

Comment: I doubt a regular webcam would survive one rainstorm, even in an enclosure.

Comment: Depends on the enclosure ... just get an enclosure designed to work on a boat and you will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

An office I worked from had an Axis [network camera](http://www.axis.com/products/cam_211w/index.htm) outside. IIRC, Axis has great software, you can get images emailed to you, put on web pages, have movement detection, etc.

---

Edit:

If you want a non-ruggedized wireless webcam, Axis has the [207w](http://www.axis.com/products/cam_207w/index.htm), which looks able to fit in your size constraints, except for a big antenna sticking out of it. Maybe you could cut a hole in the box?

Answer (score 1):

Would any of the [X10](http://www.x10.com/) cameras suffice?